# NullPointerException in EclipseLink initialization

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using Eclipselink 2.6.0-RC2 from maven repository and trying on the inheritance.

I have the 3 classes below:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, name = "CLASSNAME")
public abstract class Project {
    @Id
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String id;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Foo")
public class FooProject extends Project {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("vasp");
    private static EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Bar")
public class BarProject extends Project {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("vasp");
    private static EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

For the above configuration, both `main` in `FooProject` and `BarProject` failed with the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
```

If I removed `@Entity` description on `BarProject` then `main` on `FooProject` does not fail, and vise versa.

I have tried removing `abstract` in `Project` and assign it a `@DiscriminatorValue`, but it doesn't work.

If the `main` is placed in `Project`, it never worked too.

Is there any mistake in the annotation I am using that prevented it to work?

Comment: Remove references to `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager` from entities, move it to some new class along with `main()` method and try again.

Comment: @PredragMaric Thanks, it worked. is it illegal to request for an entity manager in the static initializer of the class? Do you know why the one with the entity manager itself work when the other is deleted?

Comment: In order for persistence unit to be initialized, all entities must  be initialized and scanned. Your setup interferes with that, with PU initializing in static variables, I wouldn't go into analysis why it works in one case and not in another since it is just wrong. Using entity manager inside entities is considered an anti-pattern by many (me included), but you'll find open debates on it on the web. I'll post the comment as the answer since it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove references to `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager` from entities, move it to some new class along with `main()` method and try again.

In order for persistence unit to be initialized, all entities must be initialized and scanned. Your setup interferes with that, with PU initializing in static variables, I wouldn't go into analysis why it works in one case and not in another since it is just wrong. Using entity manager inside entities is considered an anti-pattern by many (me included), but you'll find open debates on it on the web.